# Python bottle process reach timeout connection

Tags: python, bottle

I have a problem that after certain amount of time my bottle server is not reachable and you get connection reset- timeout connection error.

When checking if the process is running, I found it running, but after killing the process and running it again the server return to serve requests.

Any idea what it could be?
I wrapped most of my functions with exception catching , but didn't helped me to understand the problem.
I wonder if anybody has used bottle and had encountered such problem

Comment: Hard to tell without actual code. This could happen if you have an endless loop somewhere which blocks the serving thread(s) until the process is killed. You could try to add some logging to find the root of the problem.

Comment: @Andrea Cattaneo: I haven't, but I found a related error messages in my logs-  a broken pipe [errno32] and connection reset by peer, tried to handle this in different ways, without much success.
I think of changing to another server, please update also , if you find a solution

Answer (score 4):

My guess is because bottle is single threaded, and it's hanging on a request. I would suggest trying a multi-threaded server, such as cherrypy, to see if that resolves the issue. Then go back and see where the hangup was at.

Install cherrypy

```
pip install cherrypy
```

Update your python file

```
bottle.run(myapp, server='cherrypy')
```

Would need to see more code to identify any specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Al thought `cherrypy` gave me some error but I tried `tornado` and it worked.